# Is this the future of Elementary OS support beyond Loki?

Tags: discussion

There are a few main concerns I have:

- The answer rate is still low
- It feels like the community is less responsive these days
- There are lots of long-term unanswered questions (and loads of people don't mark answers as correct)
- If we're still in beta doesn't that leave our support support site at risk of removal / archive? It's now a very comprehensive resource.

I've put in a good few hours, as have many of us here, and I'd like to think that it can meet the needs and expectations of our users, but as we're likely to get a lot of new user interaction once the next release comes out, does anyone have any thoughts/suggestions on this subject?

I guess maybe that will push the community to become more active here, but I'm just not sure this is the future for us.

Comment: I was thinking about this too yesterday, I should come more often but I'm really busy now :/ Also a lot of recent questions seem to revolve around hardware issues and I don't really know how to help with those (I came now to Meta to see if there is any advise and found this thread).

Comment: Why isn't this integrated directly into Elementary OS (as a default app or a pane inside Settings)?

Answer (score 1):

Well I just got -15 rep (1 hour ago) for a solution someone changed from me and my solution was *the answer*. If the author of the question marked his, because now his is the one being accepted after mine, it could be easy to cheat the system. Ask dumb questions answer them yourself and mark/accept your as the solution.

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/17089/14940

That is wrong and because of this I lost all the enthusiasm

I know this is virtual stuff but for me was fun like playing a role game getting the next goal while helping people.

Anyway I'll continue using the system and finding solution for myself.

Thank for all the work, was fun.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I don't really understand what's going on here, it just seems enthusiasm has dwindled and will be hard to reignite...

Comment: You seem to be marked as accepted again btw.

Answer (score 1):

I support only Juno and Hera. Other versions are too old for me and it makes a unnecessary mess to answer old questions. I am trying to answer every day. Hope this will increase the quality.

Answer (score 0):

The [support page on the official website](https://elementary.io/support) now points to discussion pages on GitHub. This indicates that the elementary StackExchange is no longer the officially recommended place for community support.

Comment: "However, the [support page on the elementary website](https://elementary.io/support) links to this Stack Exchange as the official place for support." – At a glance, it seems like this is no longer true. There's no link to this site anywhere on that support page at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @V2Blast! I updated my answer.