# Is There Another Place to Ask/Answer Support Questions?

Tags: discussion

Over the last couple of months I've tried to invest a little bit of time every day to help answer people's questions about Elementary OS and Linux in general. However, it feels at times that I'm the only one here. This has me wonder whether there is a different place where support for Elementary is being carried out; be it on GitHub, a self-hosted forum, or somewhere else completely. There is a somewhat related meta question from a few years ago asking [if this Stack Exchange site was the future of support beyond Loki](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247/is-this-the-future-of-elementary-os-support-beyond-loki), but none of the answers actually answer the question.

It's taken three months to earn 207 points on here¹ meaning it will probably take at least another year before I can "level up" to start contributing to review boards or be a little more useful — and many, many more before any actions on the review boards can take place without multiple confirmations. While there's more to Stack Exchange than points, I do wonder if my time would be better spent supporting newcomers and seasoned novices of Elementary OS where there's more collaboration and interaction.

---

¹ — the first 101 points were the result of already being a "trusted" member of other SE communities

Comment: Sometimes people post questions in the elementary subreddit but the preferred place is here. I think it's just that the comunity is small so the movement is slow.

Answer (score 2):

Other places to give support are:

- [Slack](https://community-slack.elementary.io/)
- [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/)
- [Community-run Discord](https://discord.gg/pCenUBu)

The [support page on the official website](https://elementary.io/support) points to discussion pages on GitHub though. This indicates that those discussion pages are the officially recommended place for community support.

If you want to spend your support time effectively, I think it's best to be available in many places. But link to answers on GitHub when appropriate to reinforce that as the official place to get help and to make answers easy to find.

Comment: "However, the [support page on the elementary website](https://elementary.io/support) links to this Stack Exchange as the official place for support." – At a glance, it seems like this is no longer true. There's no link to this site anywhere on that support page at the moment.

Comment: Thanks! Updated!